# SVM: Why do we demand the hyperplanes to be equal $\pm 1$?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I'm following this well-known [tutorial](https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2015/06/svm-understanding-math-part-3/) on SVM.

What I'm trying to understand is why we demand the hyperplanes to be $wx - b = \pm 1$? and why is it always possible and done without loss of generality (I've understood that you can always scale $w,b$ accordingly - is that correct?)

Comment: By scaling $w$ and adjusting $b$ you could take any other positive value different from 1.

Comment: @T'x, so basically it's a matter of convenience? (since $y_i \in \{-1,1\}$, I guess)

Comment: Yes, it's convenience. (Similar to the $y_i$'s, where you could take any other values aswell, but 1 / -1 gives just a nice factor)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, we demand a hyperplane $H$ to be of the form $\vec{w}\vec{x}+b = 0$ (meaning every $\vec{x}$ that satisfies this condition is part of $H$) such that $\Vert \vec{w} \Vert$ is minimal, under constraints that $\vec{w}\vec{x}+b \ge 1 $ if $f(\vec{x})=1$ and $\vec{w}\vec{x}+b \le -1 $ if $f(\vec{x})=-1$. With $f$ the function that gives the class of a certain example $x$, in this case $1$ and $-1$ (positive and negative example). The last two conditions make sure that examples are at the correct side of the hyperplane and this is where $\pm 1$ originates.

The above minimisation problem results in a value for $w$ and $b$ in the 1-D case that maximises the margin between positive and negative examples and placed the hyperplane at the optimal position. The sideview in the slide below might clear things up as **you should not confuse the hyperplane with the red line**, the latter just represents the values of $wx+b$ for each $x$. The actual hyperplane consists of every $x$ that satisfies $wx+b=0$, in the 1-D case just a single point.

And we thus do not demand the hyperplanes to be $wx+b=\pm 1$

[image: ML17-18, lecture 6-2]